# looping through combox in a form access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, loops

I am working on access 2010 database. Im fairly new to this and have no much knowledge of VBA.

I have a form (based on a query) that display ina text box the test frequency of certain items. it's named "TestFrequency"

Then I have 3 combo boxes (named: Year1 , Year2 and Year3, respectively).

I had added a button and created an event en "Onclick", what im trying to do is to set the value of the comboboxes depending on the testfrequency value.  I also added some messagebox to popup when the event is done.

Im trying with the following code but is not working:

```
Private Sub Reset_Click()
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
 Response = MsgBox("Do you want to reset planning to default test frequency?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Planning Settings")
If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub Else
Dim ctrl AS Controls
For Each ctrl From Me.Controls
 If TestFrequency.Value = "Test Annually" Then
   Me.Year1.Value = "Yes"
   Me.Year2.Value = "Yes"
   Me.Year3.Value = "Yes"
   ElseIf TestFrequency.Value = "Test Every 2 years" Then
   Me.Year1.Value = "No"
   Me.Year2.Value = "Yes"
   Me.Year3.Value = "No"
   ElseIf TestFrequency.Value = "Test every 3 years" Then
   Me.Year1.Value = "No"
   Me.Year2.Value = "No"
   Me.Year3.Value = "Yes"
   ElseIf TestFrequency.Value = "Ad-hoc" Then
   Me.Year1.Value = "No"
   Me.Year2.Value = "No"
   Me.Year3.Value = "No"
   End If
Next ctrl
  MsgBox "Settings were changed.", vbInformation
 End If
End Sub
```

Can somebody please help me?  thanks!

Comment: You don't need for loop. And get rid of `Me.` as its within the codes of the form. I don't understand your logic in the form presentation, shouldn't `TestFrequency` be a ComboBox and when selected/changed, changes the other comboboxes (I would use CheckBox for Year1, Year2, Year3)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Patrick.  what happens is that "TestFrequency" is a value calculated from other query.  

Also, I though I would no need for loops but when i don't use loop it only change for the first item of the form (the form is based on a query and contains about 170 items).  Finally, the reason why I am using a  combobox on Year1, Year2 and Year3 is because i want to give the option to the user of customizing when each item can be tested (year 1,Year2, Year 3) while the click button is a default setting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If "Yes" in top of list, and "No" is the next, then try this (ComboBox uses `.ListIndex` to select):

```
Private Sub Reset_Click()
    If vbNo = MsgBox("Do you want to reset planning to default test frequency?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Planning Settings") Then Exit Sub
    Select Case TestFrequency.Value
        Case "Test Annually"
            Year1.ListIndex = 0
            Year2.ListIndex = 0
            Year3.ListIndex = 0
        Case "Test Every 2 years"
            Year1.ListIndex = 1
            Year2.ListIndex = 0
            Year3.ListIndex = 1
        Case "Test every 3 years"
            Year1.ListIndex = 1
            Year2.ListIndex = 1
            Year3.ListIndex = 0
        Case "Ad-hoc"
            Year1.ListIndex = 1
            Year2.ListIndex = 1
            Year3.ListIndex = 1
    End Select
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "Settings were changed.", vbInformation
End Sub
```